# How to update a value inside an object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I want to update the value inside this object to be something else. Haven't found anything that addresses this in MongoDB Docs. Here's the code:

Doc:

```
  { _id: 0,
    name: "Steel Pole",
    size: { height: 10, width: 3, uom: 'm',
    quantity: 16 }
```

Code I've tried to update the value of height:

```
db.inv.updateOne({_id: 0} , { $set: {size.height:12}})
```

The Error I get:

> Unexpected token, expected ","

Comment: add `"` around `size.height`

Comment: [This](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Tk-3w1YNX1t) is what @depperm means